# SQL - Get Sum of Values with same Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure I've done this type of operation a 1000 times before but for some reason this is not working for me.  I'm doing a report to determine if a patient receive medication on a day. So regardless if they get 1 does or 5 doses in a day the value should be 1.  Staff also do corrections on the system, that come in as negative values.  So I need to sum all of the dose value for each day, if it is a + value then its 1, otherwise its a 0.

All i want to accomplish at this point is to have 1 row for each date as either 1 or 0.

Here is my SQL Query to sum the values:

```
SELECT
    DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Short AS 'Med_Name_Short'
    , SUM(Baseline.Doses) as 'DOT'
    , Day(Baseline.Dispense_Date) as 'd_Date'
FROM    
    FACT_AMS_Baseline_Report Baseline
    INNER JOIN DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT ON Baseline.Med_Name_ID = DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Long
    INNER JOIN DIM_Date tDate ON Baseline.Dispense_Date = tDate.Date

WHERE
    Baseline.Encounter = '00000001/01'

GROUP BY
    DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Short
    , Baseline.Dispense_Date
    , Doses

Order By
    Drug_Name_Short
```

For time being I'm just pulling one encounter out of the data set to test with.
This is the output i'm getting. I also included the Day in the select just to show that the same day is coming through twice and they are not getting Summed.

Here is a sample of the output I get:

```
Med_Name_Short  DOT day of month
CEFTRIAXONE     1   15
CEFTRIAXONE     1   16
CEFTRIAXONE     4   16
CEFTRIAXONE     1   17
CEFTRIAXONE     1   18
CEFTRIAXONE     1   20
CEFTRIAXONE     -3  21
CEFTRIAXONE     1   21
CEFTRIAXONE     -1  23
PROPRANOLOL     -1  24
PROPRANOLOL     3   24
PROPRANOLOL     1   25
PROPRANOLOL     2   26
PROPRANOLOL     2   27
```

What I was hoping to see in this was that Day 16 would be a 5, day 21 would be -2 and day 24 would be -2.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be grouping by doses.  Without seeing your data, I can only guess that, for example, there are two doses of quantity 2 on the 16th.

So try:

```
SELECT
    DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Short AS 'Med_Name_Short'
    , SUM(Baseline.Doses) as 'DOT'
    , Day(Baseline.Dispense_Date) as 'd_Date'
FROM    
    FACT_AMS_Baseline_Report Baseline
    INNER JOIN DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT ON Baseline.Med_Name_ID = DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Long
    INNER JOIN DIM_Date tDate ON Baseline.Dispense_Date = tDate.Date

WHERE
    Baseline.Encounter = '00000001/01'

GROUP BY
    DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Short
    , Baseline.Dispense_Date

Order By
    Drug_Name_Short
```

Comment: should the `grouping` be on `day(dispense_date)`?

Comment: Thank you so much Jeff Hornby. What a silly mistake on my part - analysis paralysis on my part i think. Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonR So the part about wanting to  _have 1 row for each date as either 1 or 0._ wasn't important? Then why did you include it in the question? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Remove Doses from your Group By list.  You are using an aggregate function on it (SUM) which is correct, so it should not be in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're aggregating on doses you should remove it from the group by, and to get either 1 or 0 for doses use a case expression:

```
SELECT
    DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Short AS 'Med_Name_Short'
    , CASE WHEN SUM(Baseline.Doses) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'DOT'
    , Day(Baseline.Dispense_Date) as 'd_Date'
FROM    
    FACT_AMS_Baseline_Report Baseline
    INNER JOIN DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT ON Baseline.Med_Name_ID = DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Long
    INNER JOIN DIM_Date tDate ON Baseline.Dispense_Date = tDate.Date

WHERE
    Baseline.Encounter = '00000001/01'

GROUP BY
    DIM_DRUG_NAME_SHORT.Drug_Name_Short
    , Baseline.Dispense_Date 

Order By
    Drug_Name_Short
```

If the dispense_date is a datetime value you should probably use Day(Baseline.Dispense_Date) in the group by or remove the time part. 
If you group by day and your data spans over more than one month you should either limit the range or include year and month as well so that data from different months/years don't get summed up.

With your sample data you should get a result like:

```
Med_Name_Short  DOT day of month
CEFTRIAXONE     1   15
CEFTRIAXONE     1   16
CEFTRIAXONE     1   17
CEFTRIAXONE     1   18
CEFTRIAXONE     1   20
CEFTRIAXONE     0   21
CEFTRIAXONE     0   23
PROPRANOLOL     1   24
PROPRANOLOL     1   25
PROPRANOLOL     1   26
PROPRANOLOL     1   27
```